# Dropbox python api oauth2 implementation

Tags: python, dropbox

I'm trying to access my own account on dropbox with oauth2 short-lived tokens.
this is the code I've written so far. It works for now but the access token seems to never expire. Am I donig this right? I have set the default token type to short lived on dropbox app console. Thanks

```
with open(path.join(project_folder, 'access_token'), 'r') as f:
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(f.read(), oauth2_refresh_token=getenv("DROPBOX_REFRESH_TOKEN"), app_key=app_key, app_secret=app_secret)

def refresh():
    old_token = dbx._oauth2_access_token
    dbx.check_and_refresh_access_token()
    new_token = dbx._oauth2_access_token
    if new_token != old_token:
        with open(path.join(project_folder, 'access_token'), 'w') as f:
            f.write(dbx._oauth2_access_token)
            print("token refreshed")
```

Comment: Does your access token start with "sl."? If not, it's not actually a Dropbox short-lived access token. Note that changing the "Access token expiration" option on the app's page on [the App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) only applies to the default for access tokens created after changing that option.

Comment: Also, note that Dropbox short-lived access tokens are valid for four hours, so make sure you've waited that long to check if it switched over.

Comment: @Greg ِYes the access token starts with 'sl.' and I have waited almost 24 hours and  it still works. Does it even need an access token when I provide the refresh token?

Comment: No, you don't actually need to supply a short-lived access token if you supply a refresh token and app key/secret. It will get a new one for you automatically.

Comment: Also, I dug into this and I believe I see what's happening here. The `check_and_refresh_access_token` will only actually proactively get a new short-lived access token if it knows it needs to. That is, if it doesn't already have one, or knows that the one it has is definitely expired. In your case, it has one but doesn't know the expiration, so it won't bother getting a new one immediately. The SDK will automatically get a new one, if needed, when making an actual API call though, which is why it keeps working for you anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So I don't need to supply an access token in this case nor the refresh function, am I right? @Greg

Comment: Right, if you just want it to work and aren't interested in exactly if/when it's actually changing short-lived access tokens, you can just omit the initial short-lived access token as well as the `check_and_refresh_access_token` call and just let the SDK take care of it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sdk itself takes care of refreshing the token when a refresh token and app key and app secret are provided. So no need to supply an access token.